# Is there a way to use <cfhtmlhead> in cfscript?

Tags: coldfusion

I want to use `<cfhtmlhead>` in a full script component. But it appears that it has no  `<cfscript>` equivalent.

The [CFScript reference is available here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSe9cbe5cf462523a02805926a1237efcbfd5-7ffe.html).

Is there a work around to use this functionality in a full script CFC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to write a tag based version that is then included into the script based CFC. I've done this before for things like cfsetting.

Comment: No need to roll your own; someone has already done it: [CFLib: CFHTMLHEAD()](http://cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=740)